# Git integration for MonoDevelop

Tags: gratis, ide, git

[This blog post](http://blog.zerosharp.com/a-c-number-developers-adventures-in-ios-integrating-git-and-monodevelop/) talks about Git integration for MonoDevelop, but it refers to a version control menu which I don't seem to have.

Are there plugins to do Git in MonoDevelop?

Requirements:

- Show unmodified/modified/ignored files
- Let me commit easily all modified files
- Free, ideally Open source
- Compatible with the latest open source MonoDevelop

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use MonoDevelop on a Linux distribution (e.g. Ubuntu), you need to install the **VersionControl plugin for MonoDevelop** (package name: [monodevelop-versioncontrol](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/monodevelop-versioncontrol)).

> This package enables version control integration (Subversion and Git)
>   for MonoDevelop.

After the installation, you should have a menu that looks like this, more or less:

[image: VersionControl menu]

(The screenshot comes from [this old blog post](http://xfce-look.org/stories/Manish+Sinha%3A+Monodevelop+2.6+Beta+3+Git+integration?id=15204)).

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Did it work?